# Pandas Weird Date For 00:00?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

So recently I have been working on something in Excel and have found something weird I'm not sure how to deal with. Here is my excel file which I have put some random data in.

[image]

I then have the following code which writes it to a pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('excel.xlsx', engine = 'openpyxl')

duplicate_df = df.copy()
duplicate_df = df.dropna(axis = 0, how = 'all')

duplicate_df
```

However, as we can see from the dataframe, when I have 00:00 as an entry I can see a date as well? I just want the time of 00:00 instead of having a date added on in front.

[image]

But for times that aren't 00:00, the frame is fine. How can I deal with this?

Comment: `00:00` is *not* a date. That date isn't random. I suspect the field contains no data at all, or someone stored `0` in there. In Excel dates are stored as an offset from `1899-12-30 00:00:00`. If you try to display a `0` as a date in Excel, you'll get the "zero" date

Comment: I just want the time to be in there though not the date? Sorry lemme rephrase that

Comment: This isn't a matter of rephrasing. The stored value is indeed `1899-12-30 00:00:00`. If you use a display style that only shows the time part you won't see `1899-12-30`. That date hasn't changed though

Comment: How can I use a display style to only have it as a "time" if that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect a problem in Excel file. You have 2 different ways to display a time in Excel: use a time field, or use a date field and only display the time part.

Your problem is that the direct Excel access from pandas is too clever and tries to use the underlying data and not the formatted text. It helps in identifying data types, but here it drives you into unexpected data.

You have 2 ways here:

1. the nice way: fix the data in the Excel file. Then whatever processing you use on that file, you would have correct values. The problem is that is is not easy to identify the offending cells and to input correct values in them...
2. the tsv or csv workaround: as Excel knows that CSV files are text files, it writes formatted values in them. So you could export your file in csv  format and load it from pandas. The downside is that you have to re-export the file everytime it is changed.

Comment: Fix the data in Excel... well how would one represent `12:00AM` in any other way than `0`?

Comment: Yeah I have also set it so that the format of the cell is a time format of 00:00 as hh:mm so I have no clue what could be the issue there?

Comment: @BigBen: Excel cells have a value and a type. Value seems correct but type does not.

Comment: @Nhyi: Please fully read my answer... `pd.read_excel` just ignores your format.

Answer (score 0):

The issue that you are facing is arising because of the engine that is being used to parse the excel file into a pandas data frame i.e openpyxl.

If you construct a data frame without giving any value to the engine parameter(which by default is "None"), then your issue will be resolved.

Something like:

```
df = pd.read_excel('excel.xlsx')
```

in place of

```
df = pd.read_excel('excel.xlsx', engine = 'openpyxl')
```

In case, some error arises without using the engine, try using the engine and then changing the values afterward.

So,

```
df = pd.read_excel('excel.xlsx', engine = 'openpyxl')
for i in df.index:
    if 1899 == df['Start Time'].iloc[i].year:
        time = df['Start Time'][i].time()
        df['Start Time'][i] = time
```

The same can be done for "End Time".

Here, the time is stored in a temporary variable(not from the epoch, but only the timestamp), and then it is stored back into the data frame.

Comment: I tried this method but then I have the issue stating that I have a missing optional dependency 'xlrd'. Then when I install 'xlrd' I have the issue where it doesn't like my xlsx file. With openpyxl it seems to fix this issue and allows me to read my excel file in.

Comment: Nhyi why don't you simply convert your excel file to csv format. Since, excel is not suited for storing date time data, csv will work better in your case.

Comment: I realized the issue was with pandas, I no longer need an engine but the time format for 00:00 is still the same unfortunately. The task I have is to take this excel workbook in and convert it into a csv using a Python script. So I kind of have to deal with all of this in the first place unfortunately.

Comment: You can change the values after parsing it into a data frame like done above.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of messing around I find that if you have come across this error before, it is easiest to turn the whole column into a string. Then split the string into parts from where there is a space. Then take the last value. This just leaves me with the time value.